# generic message dispatching library?

Tags: c++

Is there a standard way to get rid of the switch/case block in a read loop?

i.e.

```
enum msg_type
{
    message_type_1,
    //msg types
}

struct header
{
    msg_type _msg_type;
    uint64_t _length;
}

struct message1
{
    header _header;
    //fields
}

struct message2
{
    header _header;
    //fields
}

//socket read loop
void read(//blah)
{
    //suppose we have full message here
    char* buffer; //the buffer that holds data
    header* h = (header*)buffer;
    msg_type type = h->_msg_type;

    switch(type)
    {
    case msg_type_1:
        message1* msg1 = (message1*)buffer;
        //Call handler function for this type

    //rest
    }
}
```

this means that I have to inherit from a handler container base class which is of the form:

```
class handler_container_base
{
public:
    virtual void handle(message1* msg){}
    virtual void handle(message2* msg){}
    //etc
}
```

and pass an object of that type to where the message loop can see and ask him to call those back.

One problem is, even when I want to implement and register only one handler for a single type I have to inherit from this class.
Another is this just looks ugly.

I was wondering if there are existing libraries which handle this problem (should be free). Or is there no better way of doing this rather than like this?

Answer (score 1):

Other approaches that avoid inheritance are:

1. For a closed set of types:

   Use a variant:

   ```
   variant<message1_t, message2_t> my_message;
   ```

   With a visitor you can do the rest. I recommend boost.variant.
2. You can also use a boost::any, for an open set of types, and copy the messages around at runtime.At some point you will have to cast back to the original type, though.
3. Another solution goes along the lines of Poco.DynamicAny, which will try to convert, to the type on the left in an assignment, similar to a dynamic language. But you need to register converters yourself for your types.